Can anyone help me identify this PWM IC in an SMPS? Marking: 8522B 2231
While tracing the SMPS circuit of a 24V 2A board I found this IC which seems to be a PWM controller IC.
The part marking is 8522B 2231
Anyone familiar with the symbol or where I can get the datasheet?


It's a Microne (南京微盟) ME8522BD8 if it follows the naming pattern of other Microne devices. According to this website the ME85 series are "AC/DC rectification controller". As far as I can tell, there is no datasheet or really any further information available online.
Here is an excerpt from the ME8204B datasheet to show Microne's naming conventions:

And a picture to show the marking style matches the part in question:

(Source: gys.cn)
